# Sql statement to test two columns and get results in one column without duplicating rows

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unpivot, lateral-join

I have been trying to solve how to test conditions in two different rows, and put the results into one singular column without duplicating rows.

I need to get the results in a way that pick the team name, let's say Bruins, in case that Bruins is present in either column Team1 or Team1, to later use that column (TEAM_CASES) as filter or in a group by to see if the event is completed or not.

My data looks like this:

| Event | Team1 | Team2 | Completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ducks vs Devils | Ducks | Devils | 1 |
| Ducks vs Bruins | Ducks | Bruins | 1 |

I tried using this case when syntax but it didn´t work:

```
CASE 
WHEN Team1 = "Bruins" or Team2 = "Bruins" then Bruins
WHEN Team1 = "Devils" or Team2 = "Devils" then Devils
WHEN Team1 = "Ducks" or Team2 = "Ducks" then Ducks
ELSE "Other"
END TEAM_CASES
```

The output I got was something like this, completely ignoring the results for Ducks, when it should be 2:

```
| Team   | TotalCompleted |
| ------ | -------------- |
| Bruins | 1              |
| Devils | 1              |
| Ducks  | 0              |
```

I noticed that case when only checks a records until the first condition is met, after that it moves onto the second secord

I also thought about pivoting the columns Teams1 and Teams 2, but I was in the middle of it when I realized that later I would have the same issue as before, because the data will end up like I posted belowe and I won't be able to check the conditions, because again there will be 2 conditions presents by row:

| Event | isDucks | isDevils | isBruins | Completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ducks vs Devils | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Ducks vs Bruins | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I put below my desired output, but so far, every attempt of solving this hasn't worked.

Desired Output:

| Team | Completed |
| --- | --- |
| Bruins | 1 |
| Devils | 1 |
| Ducks | 2 |

Thank you all!

Comment: All you need here is the count of rows where either Team1="Bruins" or Team2="Bruins", right?  Do you already have a table with the team names by themselves?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL to combine bith teams and use it to aggregate

```
WITH CTE as(
SELECT Team1 as Team FROM mytable WHERE Completed = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT Team2 FROM mytable WHERE Completed = 1
)
SELELCT
Team,  COUNT(*) as TotalCompleted  
FROM CTE GROUP BY Team
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to *unpivot* your dataset (while filtering on completed games). Snowflake supports [lateral joins](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join-lateral) and [row constructor `values()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/values) so we can do the work in a single table scan:

```
select x.team, count(*) completed 
from mytable t
cross join lateral ( values (t.team1), (t.team2) ) x(team)
where t.completed = 1
group by x.team
```